# Order by With Union SQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT to_user_id AS sender_id 
FROM $chat_table_name 
WHERE((to_user_id = $current_user_id OR from_user_id = $current_user_id) and post_id=$post_id)  

UNION 

SELECT from_user_id AS receiver_id 
FROM $chat_table_name 
WHERE( (from_user_id = $current_user_id OR to_user_id = $current_user_id)  and post_id=$post_id ) 

order by chat_message_id DESC
```

How to achieve order by with this query

Comment: What are you trying to order? The entire result set?

Comment: In shown state you'll receive "unknown column" error. You must add the column which is used for sorting into the output list in each subquery.

Comment: order by chat_message_id DESC @El_Vanja

Comment: That wasn't my question. I was asking if you want to order the entire result set (the whole union) or individual selects.

Comment: @El_Vanja the whole

Comment: In that case do what Akina pointed out in his comment - add the column to the result set. You can't order unions on columns that aren't included in the output.

Comment: ok thank you, let me try something else

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correct, you want to order the indivual SELECTs seperately and  you cannot use two ORDER BY clause per each statement instead, add an extra integer column to each SELECT as shown below:

```
SELECT *, 1 as orderBy from t1 
   UNION ALL
SELECT *, 2 as orderBy from t2
ORDER BY orderBy desc.
```

Comment: I want to order using  chat_message_id

Comment: But chat_message_id is not in any of your SELECTs and also is chat_message_id common in both tables?

Comment: You need to explicitly include chat_message_id in each SELECT e.g SELECT sender_id, chat_message_id FROM t1 UNION SELECT receiver_id, chat_message_id from t2 ORDER BY chat_message_id